# Replacing an invisible unicode control character in TSQL

Tags: t-sql, unicode, replace

I'm trying to search and replace an invisible unicode control character in a string in TSQL. The [control character](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/Character_reference/2000-2FFF) is 'LSEP' or `0x2028`.

I can find the character easily enough using either of these two queries:

```
SELECT * FROM Email WHERE Html LIKE '%[0x2028]%'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM Email WHERE CHARINDEX(NCHAR(0x2028) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2, Html) > 0
```

However, when I come to try and replace it, the following just doesn't work:

```
UPDATE Email
SET Html = REPLACE(Html, NCHAR(0x2028) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2, '')
WHERE Html LIKE '%[0x2028]%'
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong. I can't use the character itself using `N'LSEP'`, because it just appears as a newline in the script when I try and paste it!

Sample input, as requested:

```
</span><span> </span><span>
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample input?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't reproduce your circumstances, nor do I need the collate statement for your CHARINDEX statement to work - this fiddle shows what you've got working (notice the output length changing after the replace statement): http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=c7798b96000c893dd4f6b7b8e5bbe013

Comment: Follow on question - How did you establish that this was the control character in the column?

Comment: @Bridge It was causing a newline in a JavaScript string being rendered to the screen. As a result, the newline in the JavaScript broke the website code. When I looked at the output string coming from the database I established that it was this control character that was causing the issue (HTML email rendering sent by Outlook).

Comment: I'm still not sure how you identified this particular character. Are you sure it's not a regular new line, e.g. a combination of CHAR(10) and CHAR(13)?

Comment: @Bridge I copied the text into a good text diff editor (Beyond Compare). It shows the Unicode character as a hex code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (it replaces the unicode `LSEP` with the unicode `SPACE` char)...

```
UPDATE Email
SET Html = REPLACE(Html, NCHAR(0x2028), NCHAR(0x0020))
WHERE Html LIKE '%[0x2028]%'
```